# Gstreamer - cant record from mpjeg to ogg

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, ogg

i am trying to record output from mjpeg ( ip camera ) to ogg file using gstreamer .

i trying the following but no dice

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location='http://192.168.2.124:8081/' is-live=true do-timestamp=true ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=20/1  ! jpegdec ! theoraenc bitrate=2200 ! oggmux ! filesink location=output.ogg
```

i mean, the pipeline runs ok for a while but then, out of the blue, got a EOS signal

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:39.423928252
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

also video output of the recording is not quite rite, seems sluggish :/
weird part ... this works ok

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location='http://192.168.2.124:8081/' is-live=true do-timestamp=true ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=20/1 ! jpegdec !  jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=output.avi
```

and then i do this transcode

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=output.avi ! avidemux ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! theoraenc bitrate=2200 ! oggmux ! filesink location=output.ogg
```

i mean i got the desired result but need first to capture stream to avi and then do the transcode to ogg

Comment: Check your CPU usage. Sounds like your machine cannot transcode in realtime causing your live transcode to skip frames and eventually abort. Theoraenc may be single threaded.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information on the problem (cpu usage and looking at the logs to see who emits the EOS) but here goes one tip:

It seems you have no queues on your pipeline. It is likely that all the processing is happening on a single thread, add a queue after the decoder and one after the encoder to have separate threads dealing with decoding, encoding and muxing+saving to file.

Comment: thx for your answer, i did run with logs enabled and got this 0:00:57.049833851 28531  0x1067cc0 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2743:gst_base_src_loop:<souphttpsrc0> pausing after gst_base_src_get_range() = eos not sure why the soupthttpsrc is getting the eos btw cpu/mem usage looks fine regards